# how to check if the filed of a collection contains single value or array of values

Tags: mongodb, find

I have a collection containing documents with the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b23a2d11bc3e2550e749991"),
        "fieldA" : "field2",
        "fieldB" : [ 
            "field2", 
            "field2", 
            "field2"
        ],
        "fieldC" : "ffield2"
    },

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b23a2d21bc3e2550e749992"),
        "fieldA" : "field2",
        "fieldB" : "ffield2",
        "fieldC" : "fffield2"
    },

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b23a2d21bc3e2550e749993"),
        "fieldA" : "field1",
        "fieldB" : [ 
            "field1", 
            "field1", 
            "field1"
        ],
        "fieldC" : "ffield1"
    },

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b23a2d21bc3e2550e749994"),
        "fieldA" : "field1",
        "fieldB" : "ffield1",
        "fieldC" : "fffield1"
    },

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b23a2d31bc3e2550e749995"),
        "fieldA" : "field3",
        "fieldB" : [ 
            "field3", 
            "field3", 
            "field3"
        ],
        "fieldC" : "ffield3"
    },

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b23a2d31bc3e2550e749996"),
        "fieldA" : "field3",
        "fieldB" : "ffield3",
        "fieldC" : "fffield3"
    }
]
```

I want to find only those documents whose `filedB` is arrayed values. The value for `filedB` is unknown while firing the query. Just know that some of the documents have `fieldB` as array while others have primitive string value.

How can I find the documents whose `filedB` field has an array value?

Comment: what version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: MongoDB version v3.4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution if you are using mongodb version less than 3.2

```
db.getCollection('testCollection').find( {$where:"typeof this.fieldB !== 'string'"})
```

One comment though you should change the field value type into primitive *string* or *array*, it is not a good design to entertain both types.

If the document has single value for `fieldB` you can change it into an array of single element.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) you can use the operator `$type`; which allow to check the type of the field.

---

**Example**:

`db.data.find( { x: { $type: "minKey" } } )`

To check the `Array` type it's `4` or `'array'`.

---

@dsharew said something great. Checkout the version of mongodb you are using, changes happened with `3.2` and `3.6` about `$type`.

---

---

[image]

Comment: nice one this why I asked ;)

Comment: Thanks for replying... I tried this, but it didn't work as per my expectation :)... 
Its mentioned in the document that:
When applied to arrays, $type matches any inner element that is of the specified BSON type. For example, when matching for $type : 'array', the document will match if the field has a nested array. It will not return results where the field itself is an array.